# Как подключить файл c настройками vim?

Tags: vim

[settings file for Vim](https://google.github.io/styleguide/google_python_style.vim) (настройки google для vim для python-кода)

Как подключить этот файл и проверить, что все подключилось корректно? 
Я пробовал добавить его содержимое в файл `~/.vimrc` после `set nocp`, но ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

поместите файл в каталог `~/.vim/plugin` (создайте, если ещё не существует).

проверить, был ли интерпретирован файл, можно например, убедившись, что присутствуют переменные, определяемые в этом файле. например, `pyindent_nested_paren`.

для этого запустите *vim*, и в командном режиме (после нажатия <kbd>:</kbd>) наберите <kbd>let pyin</kbd> (т.е., первые символы названия переменной после команды *let*), затем нажмите <kbd>tab</kbd> и имя должно дополниться до `pyindent_nested_paren`.

---

**обновление**

посмотреть список всех интерпретированных файлов можно командой `scriptnames`, введя (в обычном режиме) <kbd>:scriptnames</kbd> и нажав <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Насколько я помню, загрузить файл можно через so <path/filename> (source - полная команда).